# Is it possible to increase a variables scope in C++?

Tags: c++, string, scope, char, stdstring

I'm a bit confused about how scopes should function in C++. Right now it seems to be the case that inside my else statement, my finalStr is created and then promptly destroyed after it leaves the scope.

```
std::string finalStr;
char curLine[128];
if( BINARY_ASCII == 1 ) //ignore this case please :D
{
    cdata = convertBSTRToByteArray(data , numChars);
}
else
{
    bstrInputString = ( LPCWSTR ) data;

    std::strcpy(curLine, bstrInputString.operator char *());
    std::string finalStr(curLine);

    cout << "data is: " << finalStr.data() << "\n"; //prints the right string
}

cout << "string is: " << finalStr.data() << "\n"; //prints nothing except "string is: "
```

How can I fix this? I believe I need that copy constructor in the else statement to copy over my array of chars. Is there a way around this? Thanks for reading..

Comment: You mean other than just declaring that variable outside the if-statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `finalStr` declared twice, one outside the if-else statement and one time inside. The one declared in the inner scope will **hide** the one in the outer scope, so what you have is a local variable that will be destroyed at the end of the enclosing brace.

However, `std::string` can be assigned to easily, so just use that:

```
finalStr = curLine;
```

Answer (score 2):

The very first line in your code snippet (`std::string finalStr;`) declares the `finalStr` variable.

Then, within the `else` part you're declaring another variable named `finalStr` which is local to that scope (the opening brace after the `else` to its matching closing brace). This variable now *hides* the first one, and references to `finalStr` within this scope, after the declaration, will refer to the local variable, not the `finalStr` declared in the enclosing scope.

To fix the problem, do not re-declare the variable, just assign `finalStr` a new value.

```
std::strcpy(curLine, bstrInputString.operator char *());
finalStr = curLine;
//     ^^^^^
// assign new value instead of creating another variable with the same name
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of declaring the variable in the scope you need it.  In fact, you were already doing this.  Then, don't declare it again.  Just assign it a value.  When you declare it again, a completely new variable is created (just that with the same name).  It is this second variable what is lost.

```
finalStr= curLine ;
```

It is said that the second variable is "hiding" or "shadowing" the first.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string finalStr(curLine);`

This line creates a NEW string, which just happens to have the same name as your string on the top of your code.

Change the line to this

`finalStr = curLine`

This copies `curLine` into the `finalStr` you have declared at the top.